# Make a Docker Repository a dependency in a container?

Tags: docker

I'm creating a Node.js application in Docker which calls a Python script that runs PyLucene. I currently have two containers which work: one container for the node.js side of my app which creates a node.js environment, and another container where I pulled a PyLucene docker container (https://hub.docker.com/r/coady/pylucene) and I run my PyLucene python scripts. Both of these containers work fine independently, but I'm struggling to figure out how to make the PyLucene Docker repository a dependency in my node.js container so that I can combine them.

Comment: How does one container invoke the other?  The cleanest way to do this would be to write an HTTP facade and make a network call from one container to the other, but that could be a significant amount of coding work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new Dockerfile based on one of these images, and add to it, everything you need to run the other one.

So if you take the Node.js as a base image for example, you could check what's inside the PyLucene Dockerfile to add its dependencies to a new image based on Node.js, so you will have both in one image.

The PyLycene Dockerfile:
https://github.com/coady/docker/blob/master/pylucene/Dockerfile

About the Dockerfile from the Docker docs: 
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/